# How to add "-" in django rest_framework Serializer class variables?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am writing a rest_framework Serializer class for basic validations

```
class ValidateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    client_name = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False, trim_whitespace=True)
```

and my request data contains "-" in the keys, so I need something like this

```
class ValidateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # Like the below class variable? I know it is not possible with python variable declaration.
    client-name = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False, trim_whitespace=True)
```

I've checked the [rest_framework CharField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) to find out any kwargs that allow me to accept data like
`client_name = serializers.CharField(name='client-name')`

So, is it possible to accept **-** in the Serializer class variables from request data?

Comment: Haven't tested this, but try to use `source`: `client_name = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False, trim_whitespace=True, source='client-name')`

Comment: I've tried using ```client_name = serializers.CharField(required=False, source='client-name')``` but no change.